# How to generate document for Ejabberd custom modules?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp, ejabberd-module

I have created some custom modules I need to create documentation for all my custom module So any help?

Comment: Open a text file and write the documentation, right?

Comment: No I am asking for any documentation generator

Comment: use Erlang doc or simply Edoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `edoc` - http://erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/chapter.html. Eg:
**test_edoc.erl**

```erlang
-module(test_edoc).

-export([run/1]).

%% -------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Some description
%% @end
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------
-spec run(N :: integer()) -> Result :: integer() | error.

run(N) when is_integer(N) -> N + 1;
run(_) -> error.
```

Then in Erlang shell:

```sh
1> edoc:files(["test_edoc.erl"], [{dir, doc}]).
ok
```

Then in current folder where you run `edoc:files/2` should be generated the `doc` folder, so, go to the `doc` folder and open in browser `test_edoc.html`